# Что значит “пилится как” в этом контексте?

Tags: значения, сленг

> Собсна, vcmi пилится как реверс движка

Это пост любителя Героев (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Might_and_Magic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"пилить", "запилить" is a slang for "to make, to create, to construct", usually in computer context ("запилить страницу проекта").

"пилить", "запилить" используется как сленг для "сделать", "создать", часто в компьютерном контексте ("запилить страницу проекта"). Можно заменить на "сбацать", например, чтобы понять примерное значение. Впрочем, "пилить" имеет больше вариантов действия: например, если что-то плохо запилено, можно его перепилить (переделать как надо).

Comment: Note also "выпилить" which is strightly opposite: eliminate, remove, delete. "Я вчера у него в блоге та-а-акие фотки видел, но он уже их выпилил" — "Yesterday I saw such (meaning usually "obscene" or "outright" in this context, but might be simply "great, cool") photos in his blog, but he has already removed them.

Comment: А где же классическое "Что ты мне дверь выпилил, мент?". Обращаю внимание, что пара "запилить"/"выпилить" стала мемом после ролика с "Интересной Личностью". Подробно здесь: http://lurkmore.to/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C